# ICorProfilerCallback::ClassUnloadStarted not called for a generic class, even though the class was unloaded

Tags: .net, generics, profiling, clr, clr-profiling-api

I'm currently debugging my company's CLR profiler (over ASP.NET 4.7.3282.0, .NET framework 4.7.2), and seeing a scenario in which the CLR unloads a generic class, but the [ClassUnloadStarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilercallback-classunloadstarted-method) callback is not called.

In a nutshell, our profiler keeps track of loaded classes based on ClassIDs, following the *ClassLoadStarted*, *ClassLoadFinished* and *ClassUnloadStarted* callbacks. At some point, the class gets unloaded (along with its relevant module), but the *ClassUnloadStarted* callback is not called for the relevant ClassID. Therefore, we're left with a stall ClassID, thinking that the class is still loaded. Later on, when we try to query that ClassID, the CLR unsurprisingly crashes (since it now points to junk memory).

My question, considering the detailed scenario below:

- **Why is ClassUnloadStarted not called for my (generic) class?**
- Is this an expected, edge case behaviour of the CLR, or possibly a CLR/Profiling API bug?

I couldn't find any documentation or reasoning regarding this behaviour specifically, of *ClassUnloadStarted* not being called. No hints I could find in the CoreCLR code, too. Thanks in advance for any help!

**The Detailed Scenario:**

This is the class in question ([`IComparable(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) with `T=ClassFromModuleFoo`):

```
System/IComparable`1<ClassFromModuleFoo>
```

While the application runs, the issue manifests after some modules have been unloaded.
Here's the exact load/unload callbacks flow, based on debug prints added:

1. The class `System/IComparable'1(ClassFromModuleFoo)`, of mscorlib, is loaded.
2. Immediately afterwards, the class `ClassFromModuleFoo`, of the module Foo, is loaded into assembly #1.
3. Module Foo finishes to load into assembly #1.
4. Then, module Foo is loaded again into a different assembly, #2.
5. The `IComparable` and `ClassFromModuleFoo` are loaded again, this time in assembly #2. Now there are two instances of each class: one in Foo loaded in assembly #1, and one in Foo loaded in assembly #2.
6. Module Foo begins to unload from assembly #1.
7. `ClassUnloadStarted` callback is called for `ClassFromModuleFoo` in assembly #1.
8. Module Foo finished to unload from assembly #1.
9. `ClassUnloadStarted` is **not** called for `System/IComparable'1(ClassFromModuleFoo)` of assembly #1 anytime later (even though its module unloaded and its ClassID points to now thrashed memory).

Some additional information:

- The issue also reproduces with the latest .NET framework version, 4.8 preview.
- I've disabled native images by adding `COR_PRF_DISABLE_ALL_NGEN_IMAGES` to the profiler event mask, thinking it may impact the ClassLoad* callbacks, but it didn't made any difference. I verified that `mscorlib.dll` in indeed loaded instead of its native image.

**Edit:**

Thanks to my very smart colleague, I was able to reproduce the issue with a small example project, that simulates this scenario by loading and unloading of AppDomains. Here it is:
https://github.com/shaharv/dotnet/tree/master/testers/module-load-unload

The crash occurs for this class in the test, which is unloaded, and for which the CLR didn't call the unload callback:

```
Loop/MyGenList`1<System/String>
```

Here's the relevant code, which is loaded and unloaded a few times:

```
namespace Loop
{
    public class MyGenList<T>
    {
        public List<T> _tList;

        public MyGenList(List<T> tList)
        {
            _tList = tList;
        }
    }

    class MyGenericTest
    {
        public void TestFunc()
        {
            MyGenList<String> genList = new MyGenList<String>(new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" });

            try
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

At some point, the profiler crashes trying to query the ClassID of that class - thinking it's still valid, since the unload callback was not called for it.

On a side note, I tried porting this example to .NET Core for investigating further, but couldn't figure out how, since .NET Core doesn't support secondary AppDomains (and I'm not very sure it supports on-demand assembly unloading in general).

Comment: It is unclear to me how this snippet and the github project could be helpful.  Surely this is a flaw in your ClassUnloadStarted implementation.  You must assume that the order in which it is called is undefined, so it is only safe to query info about *classId*.  Querying anything else gives you fifty-fifty odds for a crash since the type might have already unloaded.  Invariably 100% at SO.  And for generic types that you only get a callback for the "open type", MyGenList<> in the snippet.  Copy/paste your ClassUnloadStarted code to get a better guess.

Comment: @HansPassant, Many thanks for you reply. My profiler keeps track of relevant ClassIDs using ClassLoadStarted and ClassLoadFinished callbacks. For the class in question, the ClassUnloadStarted callback is never called, although I can clearly see it was unloaded (seeing the ClassID address in the debugger, and its module unloaded). So I'm left with a stall ClassID that crashes whenever I try to query about it (I try to query about it, since I have no idea it was unloaded). RE post at SO: I see your point - only later it occured to me I should have posted at MSDN CLR forum - I may do so later on.

Comment: RE: ClassUnloadStarted implementation: unfortunately I can't share the ClassUnloadStarted code as is, since it's my company's code, but I can say that it works the same for any non-array class - it just does cleanup operations for the given ClassID and removes it from the relevant structures.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand I may have overemphasized on the specifics of loading order of the generic class and its type - I edited my question, trying to make it clearer.

Comment: Also posted on MSDN CLR forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06f3022d-0d6e-450c-8100-9e082fb21ee1/icorprofilercallbackclassunloadstarted-not-called-for-a-generic-class-instantiation-even-though?forum=clr#06f3022d-0d6e-450c-8100-9e082fb21ee1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making it possible in .Net Core (unloading wasn't supported before 3.0), we managed to replicate it (thanks valiano!). It is confirmed to be a bug by coreclr team (https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/26126).

From davmason's explanation:

> There are three separate types involved and each callback is only
>   giving you two (but a different set of two).
>
> Plugin.MyGenList1: the unbound generic type Plugin.MyGenList1
>   : the generic type bound to thecanonical type (used
>   for normal references) Plugin.MyGenList1 : the generic
>   type bound to System.String. For ClassLoadStarted we have logic that
>   that specifically excludes unbound generic types (i.e.
>   Plugin.MyGenList1) from being shown to the profiler in
>   ClassLoader::Notify
>
> This means you ClassLoadStarted only gives you callbacks for the
>   canonical and string instances. This seems the right thing to do here,
>   since as a profiler you would only care about bound generic types and
>   there's nothing of interest for unbound ones.
>
> The issue is that we do a different set of filtering for
>   ClassUnloadStarted. That callback occurs inside EEClass::Destruct, and
>   Destruct is only called on non-generic types, unbound generic types,
>   and canonical generic types. Non-canonical generic types ( i.e.
>   Plugin.MyGenList1  ) are skipped.